# IEnumerable.Min() returns strange results with generic objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, visual-studio-2015

If I have a list of objects (say, `List(Of Foo)`) and I wanted to get the minimum value of a specific property among the elements of the list, I could use something like:

```
listOfFoo.Min(Function(i) i.Id)
```

No problem with that. Now, if the list happens to be empty, the above code won't work. So, I use something like:

```
listOfFoo.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(Function(i) i?.Id).GetValueOrDefault()
```

That also works perfectly fine ***until the list becomes a list of generic objects*** then it starts to return very strange results.

**Code to reproduce the issue:**

```
Class Foo
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Class Bar
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Function GetMin(list As List(Of Foo)) As Integer
    Return list.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(Function(i) i?.Id).GetValueOrDefault()
End Function

Function GetMin(Of T As Bar)(list As List(Of T)) As Integer
    Return list.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(Function(i) i?.Id).GetValueOrDefault()
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim fooList As New List(Of Foo) From {New Foo() With {.Id = 2}, New Foo() With {.Id = 3}}
    Dim min = GetMin(fooList)
    Console.WriteLine(min)      ' 2 --> Great!

    Dim barList As New List(Of Bar) From {New Bar() With {.Id = 2}, New Bar() With {.Id = 3}}
    Dim min2 = GetMin(Of Bar)(barList)
    Console.WriteLine(min2)     ' 12 --> Huh?!!!!

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

As the comments show, the second list returns `12` even though it has the same values as the first one. Also, you would notice that the returned value isn't random; it changes along with the properties of the class. For example, if I add another string property to `Bar`, it returns `606600` instead of `12`!

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Update:** I think it might be a bug in VB.NET because I just tried doing the same thing in C# and it returned the correct value. [Here's the C# code](https://pastebin.com/kGKKa6FT) if someone wants to have a look. I used .NET 4.5.2 for both but I also tested on .NET 4.6.1 with VB and it still didn't work right.

**Update #2:**

I'm using VS2015. The problem seems to go away when I switch to VS2017 (same .NET versions).

Comment: I ran your code using linqpad & it returns the value 2 for both. Have you pasted the full code that one can run and compare?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I'm using VS. Let me try LinqPad and see.. Edit: Yes, you can pretty much copy and paste the code as is.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I tried with LinqPad but it doesn't even compile (looks like LinqPad doesn't recognize the null-conditional operator syntax). I tried using the free edition v4.59.

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B10ox9#) I used. I had to make a couple of changes though. It prints 2 twice.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I think you might've shared the wrong link but nonetheless, you don't have to write something from scratch (unless you want to) as the code in the question is an MCVE.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D5udr1 I dont know how it can print 12 when you have added a property which had Id in 2 & 3. Perhaps, you can reopen VS.net and build/run the code again?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Yes, that version definitely works but I never said it wouldn't. The reason I used nullable is to cover the case where the list has no elements. If you remove that (like what you did in the fiddle), it won't work with empty lists (you get a NullReferenceException).

Comment: It won't just return 12, it'll return other very strange results as well (as mentioned in the question above). I know you're trying to help but I don't know why you keep insisting on trying different code when you can simply copy and paste my code and you'll be able to reproduce :)

Comment: I could run your code in linqpad & could not run without errors on dotnetfiddle (hence the code changes). I have no clue why it would print 12 or 606600

Comment: @shahkalpesh Well, I'm as puzzled as you are! I added another update to the question though (I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on VS2017). This is very weird!

Comment: It might be interesting to compare the IL generated by VS 2015 to the IL generated by VS 2017 (or even to decompile in ILSpy and check on the differences).  I'd guess a compiler bug is either making it call the wrong thing (e.g. GetHashCode instead of get_Id) or pointing the retrieval of Id at the wrong spot in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the updates to the question, this seems to be producible on specific versions of Visual Studio (produced on VS2015 but not on 2017) so I *think* it's a bug in the VB compiler used in VS2015.

Unfortunately, I can't upgrade this project to VS2017 at the moment, so as a workaround, I'm replacing this line:

```
min = listOfFoo.DefaultIfEmpty().Min(Function(i) i?.Id).GetValueOrDefault()
```

With:

```
min = If(listOfFoo.Count = 0), 0, listOfFoo.Min(Function(i) i.id)
```

..which does the same thing although I prefer the former in terms of readability.